# CSS GRID Auto-Fill, button overlap, depends on the resolution

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In using CSS Grid Auto-fill, I have one button that overlaps another depending on the screen size.  I have them in their own HTML section, which contains two div's, each button is in it's own div.

What can be done to prevent the overlap no matter the resolution?  Also, how do I ensure the buttons only stay 3px apart no matter the resolution?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pd6nkcxz/2/) does not recreate the problem.  It may be a Telerik issue, but I'm not sure if it's an autofill issue.

**HTML:**

```
            <section class="sectionSaveChecked">

                <div class="itemBtnJump">
                    <telerik:RadButton ID="Jump" runat="server" Text="Jump to Management">
                        <Icon PrimaryIconCssClass="rbNext"></Icon>
                    </telerik:RadButton>
                </div>

                <div class="itemBtnSaveChecked">
                    <telerik:RadButton ID="SavePlacedChecked" runat="server" Text="Save Checked">
                        <Icon PrimaryIconCssClass="rbSave"></Icon>
                    </telerik:RadButton>
                </div>

            </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
        .sectionSaveChecked {
            display: grid;
            grid-gap: 3px;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: would it be possible to post a fiddle or codepen for this question?

Comment: is your icon in absolute position ?

Comment: No, there is no absolute position, I will try to work up a codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How this was fixed was to set the width on the buttons and to change the grid-template columns to;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 220px);

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has something to do with 'telerik'.  I re-created a simple version of the above with normal HTML/CSS markup and could not re-create the issue.  What I did notice though after visually looking at it, is that most likely the text and the button have conflicting margins and/or padding.  So the grid, is most likely viewing only one of these items in it's calculations but not the other, which may be leading to this 'overlapping'.

Simply put, I believe the grid may be viewing the width of the button prior to the text's influence on said button. When you display:grid on a container, it only influences the children of the container, not the grandchildren.

One possible path you could take towards a solution is to try and set the width of the child divs to 200px ("itemBtnJump" and "itemBtnSaveChecked") and then see if the overlapping persist.

Comment: I appreciate the response!  Changing the width's does prevent overlap.  However there is some gap between the buttons I'd like to prevent.  I'd like the buttons to maintain 3px apart, currently they go about 50px apart before filling back close.  How do I keep the distance 3px using auto-fill please?  Thank you.

Comment: @JM1 you could try and set the display of both divs to `inline-block`, without assigning a width to them.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasScheffer.  I appreciate your response.  When i do that, the button wraps and goes under the first button.